# Sharing product subscriptions between multiple computers

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, product-key

I'll start with a hypothetical situation, say I have a personal licence for Adobe Cloud and have 8 computers with me.

[According to Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/download-install/using/install-apps-number-of-computers.html), I can have 2 computers activated on a single subscription at a time.

But what if I want to configure all of my 8 systems such that if I log into **any one** of the 8 systems, my products are activated (given that I have at most 2 computers running at a time, thus meeting the Adobe's license agreement).

Now those machines can be VMs running on a local server or on Azure/ GCP that's not a limitation, but I think they would have to be on a Windows machine as I'm planning to use products such as AutoCAD, Rhino, Adobe suite, etc.

Comment: “But what if I want to configure all of my 8 system - That requires 4 subscriptions.  You can contact Adobe to confirm your options.

Comment: As per https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask and _hypothetical_ questions: _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face._

Comment: This is a legal question and you should consult their documentation on licence activation. Typically the use case you are wanting is referred to as a "floating" licence, but I suspect that Adobe doesn't support it and instead locks licenses to machines for some time and restricts the number of activations/deactivations on a month by month basis. If you need licences for more computers then contact Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abobe will disagree. They will interpret the license terms as one installation = one activation. They have more lawyers than you do, and the coders to back it up through making the app phone home it they want. Bless your heart, have a nice day, and [resistance is futile](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/39/Vogon_poetry2.jpg/250px-Vogon_poetry2.jpg).